# Allow slashes in route parameter on React

Tags: reactjs, react-router-v4

I have a router like this:

```
<Route path="/blog/:date/:folder" render={(props: any) => <Home />
```

It works with this:

```
http://localhost/blog/2017-05-20/test
```

However, `:folder` can have slashes (sub-dir) and i want to parse all path at once in folder.

This is **not** working:

```
http://localhost/blog/2017-05-20/test/sub/dir
```

In this situation, I only get `test`. I want to get `:folder` as `test/sub/dir` as a whole.

Is there any way to achieve this with React Router?

**Expected**:

```
:date => '2017-05-20'
:folder => 'test/sub/dir'
```

**Actual:**

```
:date => '2017-05-20'
:folder => 'test'
```

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Yes, you can do this by adding a `+` to your Route path. So, like this:

```
<Route path="/blog/:date/:folder+" ... />
```

[This library](https://github.com/pillarjs/path-to-regexp) is being used for matching the path. So for more advanced matching cases this is a better place to look at then the React Router docs.

Comment: Please not that the library referenced is not used with React Router v6, and this solution does not work. Instead a wildcard `*` may work depending on your usecase.

Comment: For me, the `.../:folder*` will resolve to the route, but the folder param in the component resolves only to the first segment of the :folder (ex, 'test/sub/dir` ... folder useParams would just be `test`)

Comment: Discussed further in this issue, with no resolution: https://github.com/remix-run/react-router/issues/8254

Answer (score 1):

You can recursively embed components if they're rendered by a Route - you could then check `this.props.match` for a path name, for example, in your base Router, you'd have the basic route, `/blog/:date`, which renders a Home component.

Then inside the Home component, you could render another Route (it still works from here, despite not being an immediate child of the Router) with a set up like

```
<Route path={`${this.props.match.url}/:folder`} component={Folder} />
```

Then inside the Folder component you would render the same Route, which will progressively render sub-components for each `/:folder` in the path.

The `match` object also includes `isExact` which you could use to determine if you're on the last level of the folder structure from the URL.

Source: See [this example](https://medium.freecodecamp.org/hitchhikers-guide-to-react-router-v4-21c99a878bf8) of embedded routes.