# Fetching Url type id with useParams (React Router)

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I'm fetching news articles from The Guardian API. Article id's are like this: "world/live/2020/dec/31/coronavirus-covid-live-news-updates-vaccine-lockdown"

I need to go from article summary to article details and I'm using React Router for this. If I use `const { id } = useParams();` and console log it, it gets only gets "world" form the id. How can I get the full id?

```
<Route path="/:id" component={ArticlePage} />

    {topStories.map((story) => (
      <Link to={`/${story.id}`}>
        <ImageCard key={story.id} story={story} />
      </Link>
    ))}
```

Comment: Please update your question to include a [Minimal, Complete, and Reproducible](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) code example. Can we see how you've defined your routes and also how you construct your links to them?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Allow slashes in route parameter on React](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56133182/allow-slashes-in-route-parameter-on-react)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Issue

Path `"/:id"` will only match the first path "segment", i.e. "world" from `"world/live/2020/dec/31/coronavirus-covid-live-news-updates-vaccine-lockdown"`.

## Solution

If the path is `"world/live/2020/dec/31/coronavirus-covid-live-news-updates-vaccine-lockdown"` and you are trying to get `coronavirus-covid-live-news-updates-vaccine-lockdown` as the id then you need to define a route path that matches what you want to extract.

Something like

```
<Route path="/world/live/:year/:month/:day/:id" component={ArticlePage} />
```

Now using the params you can extract any of these, including the `id`.

```
const { day, id, month, year } = useParams();
```